Different hero background images on pc and mobile devices
On my page, i have a hero section with a background image and a title. The image size is 1920x500px.

<section class="bgimage d-flex align-items-center " style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),url(https://mikulas.web87.hu/images/site_background/7304-1.jpg)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <h1 class="bgimage_title text-white">Rendelés menete</h1>
        <!--<p class="bgimage_text text-white"></p>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

On a full hd monitor, everything works fine, but on mobile and small devices, the image size and position isnt the best, so i would like to change the image.
You can see my page here:

<ul class="bxslider"><li>
                            <picture>
                              <source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="https://mikulas.web87.hu/images/homepage_slideshow/18-1.jpg" />
                              <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="https://mikulas.web87.hu/images/homepage_slideshow/300-1.jpg" />
                              <img src="https://mikulas.web87.hu/images/homepage_slideshow/300-1.jpg" alt="" />
                            </picture>
                         </li></ul>

I only tried searching for some sample codes, but didnt find any for this, with different images given.

Does this answer your question? making background images responsive

Instead of using the image with the same aspect ratio, crop the image to the content you want to display on the mobile devices. You can create 3 variations, one for the desktop, one for tablet, and last one for mobile phones.

I understand what you are trying to say, If you need a different image according to the size of the device the user is visiting your site, I would recommend you to use the srcset attribute on the img element. Here is an example code:


/* Basic Section Styling */
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    /* aspect-ratio: 16 / 9; You can use also use Aspect Ratio of 1920x1080 */
}

/* This pseudo-class is for the overlay effect */
section::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

/* This will be the image that will be displayed */
img {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* This is to place the content above the image */
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
<section class="bgimage d-flex align-items-center">
    <img
        src="https://placehold.co/3200x800.png"
        srcset="
            https://placehold.co/800x200.png   800w,
            https://placehold.co/1600x400.png 1600w,
            https://placehold.co/3200x800.png 3200w
        "
    />
    <!-- 1st URL image will be shown if the screen size is equal or less than 800px -->
    <!-- 2nd URL image will be shown if the screen size is equal or less than 1600px -->
    <!-- 3rd URL image will be shown if the screen size is equal or less than 3200px -->

    <!-- You will put your image URL with the desired width of the screen -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h1 class="bgimage_title text-white">Rendelés menete</h1>
                <!-- Your rest of the content goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



Points to be noted:

If you have already loaded the larger image of the first reload of the browser, reducing the size of the screen afterward will not change the image back to the small size and it will remain at the large size
If you want to see the small image, you must hard reload your browser (Ctrl + F5) to clear the image from the browser's caches.
User screen size is obviously not adjustable so if they will first open it on the small screen this will not cause any issues for users.

If you want a details and full explanation of how the srcset works I would highly recommend you to read this blog, I have also used this blog as a reference to answer your question.
Blog Link and Credit goes to : https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2023-05/responsive-images/
